# Mapping and searching on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a table called orders. On this table i have 6 columns: **id, agent_type, agent_id, amount, customer_number, created_at**

```
|id|agent_type             |agent_id  |amount|customer_number|created_at         |
|--|-----------------------|----------|------|---------------|-------------------|
|1 |App\Models\Customer    | 1        |50    |+88015456752   |2019-05-10 11:50:11|
|2 |App\Models\Customer    | 1        |20    |+88015454589   |2019-05-11 11:50:11|
|3 |App\Models\Partner     | 1        |30    |+88017457789   |2019-05-15 11:50:11|
|4 |App\Models\Customer    | 3        |30    |+88016445649   |2019-05-14 11:50:11|
```

We are getting some data based on **agent_type, agent_id** and a like query on **customer_number** -

```
select * from orders where agent_type = "App\Models\Customer" AND agent_id = 1 AND customer_number like "%01545%"
```

> Now we wants to query in **ELASTICSEARCH**. So what is the best approach to set mapping and analyzer and **querying** to get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to do a partial match on `customer_number`

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and results.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "agent_type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "agent_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "amount": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "customer_number": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer":"standard"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "agent_type": "App\\Models\\Customer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "agent_id": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customer_number": "01545"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66505400",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "agent_type": "App\\Models\\Customer",
          "agent_id": 1,
          "amount": 50,
          "customer_number": "+88015456752",
          "created_at": "2019-05-10 11:50:11"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66505400",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "agent_type": "App\\Models\\Customer",
          "agent_id": 1,
          "amount": 20,
          "customer_number": "+88015454589",
          "created_at": "2019-05-11 11:50:11"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: thank you so much. i have also another question. If i wants to query like this - select * from orders where agent_type = "App\Models\Customer" AND agent_id = 1 AND (customer_number like "%01545%" or customer_name like "%pasha%"). How could we do that ?